# How do to replace ^A characters with tr

Tags: bash, unix, tr

I want to replace ^A characters with \n with tr. 
I dont have a clue what ^A represents.
What ASCII code shall I use for ^A ?

Answer (score 1):

`^A` means ASCII 0x01 (SOH). You can remove it with `tr -d '\001'`.

The ASCII control characters are often represented in this way, with `^X` having the ASCII code of X minus 0x40.

- ASCII 0 (NUL) is ^@
- ASCII 1 (SOH) is ^A
- ASCII 2 (STX) is ^B
- ...

You can produce them by pressing `Ctrl-@`, `Ctrl-A`, `Ctrl-B`, ...